# How can I use two different arrays to spawn two different objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a HTML5 game and I'm having trouble spawning the coins that will appear at the bottom of the screen. I have another object that is randomly spawning blocks that are falling from the top of the screen. When I add the function for spawning coins, the spawning of the blocks doesn't work and the console error says that it can't define something or other. Is there something wrong with my functions?

```
function animateRandomBlocks()
    {
        var time = Date.now();
        if(time>lastSpawn+spawnRate)
        {
            lastSpawn = time;
            spawnRandomBlocks();
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++)
        {
            var block = blocks[i];
            block.y += spawnRateOfDescent;

            if (block.status == 1)
            {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = block.type;
            ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
            ctx.closePath();
            }

            var blockRight = block.x;
            var blockLeft = block.x + block.width;
            var blockTop = block.y
            var blockBottom = block.y + block.height;
            var bobRight = bobX;
            var bobLeft = bobX + bobWidth;
            var bobTop = bobY;
            var bobBottom = bobY + bobHeight;

        if (blockRight > bobLeft && blockLeft < bobRight && blockBottom > bobTop && blockTop < bobBottom && block.status == 1)
        {
            block.status = 0;
        }

    }
    }
```